# Sort ParseQuery by boolean field

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to sort my query first if a field is true or false, and then by updatedAt. How do I achieve this on Android with Parse SDK?

My current code is:

```
mQuery.orderByDescending("draft");
mQuery.addAscendingOrder("updatedAt");
```

But I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to sort by key draft.

Answer (score 1):

First parse the query with draft values true with ascending order of updateTime and store the values to an array. After fetching this parse the query with draft values false.

```
ArrayList<ParseObject> result=new ArrayList();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
query.whereEqualTo("draft", true);
query.orderByAscending("updatedAt");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      result=object;
       ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
       query1.whereEqualTo("draft", false);
       query1.orderByAscending("updatedAt");
       query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
         public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
           if (object == null) {
              Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
           } else {
              result=object;
              for(int i=0;i<object.size();i++)
              {
                 result.add(object.get(i));
              }
           }
         }
       });
    }
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    mquery.whereEqualTo("True","draft");
```

instead of orderByDescending.

Comment: But I want to have the true results first and then the results with the status draft == false.